# display error message on same page for login

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display error message on same page. I know i have to use javascript. This is my code so far. However it says 1 after. I thnk this is from my numrows!==0 how would i get rid of this 1.

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
{
    $host_name = 'localhost';
$db_user ='root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'login';
/* Connect to MySQL */
 $con = mysql_connect("$host_name","$db_user","$db_pass") or die ("Couldn't connect!");
 $db = mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("Couldn't connect to database!");

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
 if ($numrows!=0)
 {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $dbusername = $row['username'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];

    }
    /*Check to see if they match! */
    if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
    {
        echo "You're in! <a href='member.php'> Click</a> here to enter the member page";
            $_SESSION['username']==$username;
    }
    else
        echo "Incorrect password";
    }
     else
        die("That user doesn't exist!");

    echo $numrows;
 }
 else
    die("Please enter username and/or password!");

?>
```

Comment: Your code is higly vulnerable to mysql injection

Comment: Just remove echo $numrows;

Comment: Ok thanks , please advise on the java

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need JavaScript to do this. You can do it in PHP. As shown below.

I've modified your PHP code. Place this in the file where you perform login.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (!empty($username) && !empty($password))
    {
        $host_name = 'localhost';
        $db_user ='root';
        $db_pass = '';
        $db_name = 'login';

         $con = mysql_connect($host_name, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("Couldn't connect!");
         $db = mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("Couldn't connect to database!");

         $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=".mysql_real_escape_string($username)." and password = ".mysql_real_escape_string($password));
         $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

         if($numrows == 1)
         {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username; //Store username to session for futher authorization 
            header("Location: member.php"); //Redirect user to home page
         }
         else {
                $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "Invalid username or password";
         }
        header("Location: login.php"); //Redirect user back to your login form
     }
     else {
        die("Please enter username and/or password!");
      }

    ?>
```

And simply do something like this on your login form.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
    <html>
    <body>
        <div id="errMsg">
            <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['errMsg'])) { echo $_SESSION['errMsg']; } ?>
        </div>
        <?php unset($_SESSION['errMsg']); ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: I made the following changes however it still leads to aniother page for incorrect password but above it  i get undefined index for username and password: I keep getting this when i include the session start when i remove it i dont get those errors i also noticed when i hit the back button it displays Invalid username & password right above my login form sometimes.

Comment: @user3369387 You need to put the login code into a separate file something called "login-check.php" and the HTML code into another file something like "login.php" then set the action in this file to "login-check".php